# Input string was not in correct format expected type is Int32

Tags: c#

How do i resolve this error
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in EmpID Column.  Expected type is Int32

```
 DataSet info = this.GetData.getInfo("SELECT 0 AS ErNo,Er.EmpID,(Er.FName&' '&Er.MName&' '&Er.LName) AS [Employee Name], ss.DeptNo AS [Dept No] FROM (EmpReg AS Er INNER JOIN EmployeeDept AS ss ON Er.EmpId = ss.EmpId) WHERE ss.DeptId=" + (object)DeptID + " AND ss.Status=0 AND Er.EmpStatus=1 ORDER BY " + str, "EmployeeDept");
 var tbl = info.Tables[0];   
 tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
      index, 
      tbl.Rows[index]["Employee Name"].ToString(), 
      tbl.Rows[index]["Dept No"].ToString(), 
      tbl.Rows[index]["EmpId"] 
    };
```

Comment: What is the value you try to store?

Comment: try this Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows[index]["EmpId"])

Comment: thanks @Krishna,i have already tried that  but the same error still shows up

Comment: What's the value inside tbl.Rows[index]["EmpId"] ?can check in debug ?

Comment: Its employee name

Comment: Well, the column-type is `Int32` but you say it is the name of the employee. This name is not an integer, that's the reason for the exception. Maybe you are using the wrong column or the column-type should be changed to `String`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter may be this error message might help      "Couldn't store <John Doe> in EmpID Column.  Expected type is Int32 "  basically it is picking the employee name but failing to store it in EmpId column,so am wondering how i can convert it to Int32 type.I have tried several ways but in vain

Comment: @karcs: have you read my comment? Of course `Jon Doe` is not an integer and you will never be able to convert it to one. You have to show more of your code, where do you fill or initialize the table?

Comment: Wow! Just wow! Could somebody delete this question please? It will help nobody and will just clutter SO. The OP needs to learn the basics of coding and the basics of how to ask a question. SO is not a learning from scratch tool.

Comment: @RacilHilan You know the process: you vote to close for a valid close reason. Then if OP doesn't improve their question, it will get auto-deleted by the Roomba.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Here is the other part of the code   DataSet info1 = this.GetData.getInfo("SELECT 0 AS ErNo,Er.EmpID,(Er.FName&' '&Er.MName&' '&Er.LName) AS [Employee Name], ss.DeptNo AS [Dept No] FROM (EmpReg AS Er INNER JOIN EmployeeDept AS ss ON Er.EmpId = ss.EmpId)  WHERE ss.DeptId=" + (object)DeptID + " AND  ss.Status=0  AND Er.EmpStatus=1 ORDER BY " + str, "EmployeeDept");

            var tbl = info.Tables[0];

Comment: @karcs: always edit your question if you want to improve it or provide additional informations.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I agree and that's what we all do, myself included. But after reading the comments, do you really think this question is salvageable? (i.e. can be improved in anyway that is useful for other SO users)

Comment: That doesn't matter. We can't delete it unless it is closed, and why delete it if the Roomba does already? @RacilHilan

Comment: @PatrickHofman Oh, sorry. I should've said "close" :-). Of course, close and then delete.

Comment: What is `EmpReg`? What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: @PatrickHofman   EmpId is Int,Employee Name is String,DeptId is Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of columns in `tbl` is defined in the SELECT-statement. So your table has the following columns:

- ErNo (as an int)
- EmpID (I assume it is an int)
- Employee Name (a string)
- Dept No (I assume it is an int)

Next you are trying to add a new row, but the order of the datavalues you put in, is in the incorrect order. Furthermore, you are trying to convert the fields, which are already of the correct type, to a string. Try this:

```
tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
  index, 
  tbl.Rows[index]["EmpId"] // This field is moved two fields to the left / up.
  tbl.Rows[index]["Employee Name"], // Without the ToString.
  tbl.Rows[index]["Dept No"], // Without the ToString.
};
```